# PHP - Form handling

Tags: php, html, forms, post

On clicking the submit query button, it should display the information the user has entered but it is not happening here. Where is the mistake? 
Here is the html code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="temp2.php">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" ><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="e-mail" ><br>
            <input type="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>`
```

And the temp2.php file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Name: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
        E-mail: <?php echo  $_POST["e-mail"]; ?><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

[This is the image of the output when Submit button is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnVLU.png)

Comment: this should work. what's showing and what's not showing? errors if any? running this from your own machine? is a webserver/PHP installed? the list goes on... and hoping comments don't go unseen here.

Comment: I have added an image of the output that I'm getting. I have xampp installed and running if it matters in this case.

Comment: make sure it's properly installed then. check for errors.

Comment: Try using `email` instead of `e-mail`. Else put a `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` to see all sent post-data.

Comment: @zwergmaster that shouldn't matter. hyphens only fail for variables and not POST arrays.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What kind of errors am I looking at?

Comment: consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and set it up to catch and display.

Comment: You say xampp is running, but you left this under an answer: *"Do we need xampp to be running to test this? – Vasu Mistry"* - I don't get it. and where does "Welcome" come from? You're not showing us your real code here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just a guess, sometimes you copy and paste something and you use some specialchars in your code like a ndash or so.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, xampp is running on my pc and the code is working fine on that user's pc, I have no clue of why it is not on mine.

Comment: @zwergmaster You have a point there. OP shows us an image with "Welcome" but it's not in their code, which implies not actual code. I voted to close this.

Comment: how are you accessing those files? as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or `C:\xamp\htdocs\file.xxx` or `file:///c:/xamp/htdocs/file.xxx`? there's a difference here. and if from a browser or other?

Comment: I've changed the image in the question. I might have realised my mistake, just a minute. Please do take a look at the image though

Comment: and that mistake being what exactly? and make sure you did enter something in the inputs.

Comment: I had those files in php folder and not in htdocs folder. It's up and running now, thank you everyone.

Comment: error reporting as I said earlier, would have told you that; "file not found"

Comment: I posted my answer below which you really should mark as solved, after all we've been through here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(now that we know what was NOT going on here)

OP:

> *"I had those files in php folder and not in htdocs folder. It's up and running now, thank you everyone."*

- [Link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462789/php-form-handling/33463242#comment54712133_33462789)

Having used error reporting would have thrown you a notice about that file/folder not being found.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Something to which I pointed out very much earlier in the comments area.

Your best bet when coding is to check if a folder/file exists in the first place and inside a conditional statement.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

and checking if your inputs are set/not empty:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it's working just fine. Make sure that your **html** and **temp2.php** files are in the same directory.

Comment: This really needs to be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: Do we need xampp to be running to test this?

Comment: @DeveloperX I upvoted your answer because that's what the real problem was from the start and felt you needed to know. After all the commenting back and forth, their question was unclear from the get-go.

Comment: It takes one to know one... happy coding :D

Comment: @DeveloperX :-) *Cheers*